# How to download a file from ftp on server and then use import data from it

Tags: php, mysql, server

Hi I have build a script that downloads files from ftp account and then import data from them. However it works on localhost as after downloading files I save them on c drive and then read the files from there and process them. I need help to do this on live server. How can I achieve this and where can I store the files on server outside public_html folder.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me please. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a code snippet you tried to use. It would help people answering your question greatly! Read more about [how to ask a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Yes, it will be good to store the files outside public_html
- You can create download folder outside public_html using various tools. Log into you host provider account and use file manager tools there or else you can get an SSH credential for the host and create the folder using some SSH client
- Also give proper permission to the folder, so that we can write/ read from it.
- You can refer the location of the download folder from script using the script $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .(Replace public_html with down load folder name)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have created folder outside public_html and storing files in there but my script cannot access it for some reason. Would you please be able to help me

Comment: when I printed my '$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].path_to_file' it is printing /home/tradedev/public_html/trade_files/files.csv when the file is in path /home/tradedev/trade_files/file.csv

Comment: Try this , $path_to_filename=str_replace("public_html","trade_files",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/trade_files/files.csv ");

Answer (score 0):

this is not a very specific question, but sounds like you need to check permissions on your download folder on the server, set permissions so that your script can save into it, and you may want to keep it outside of public_html so that it is not accessible via the web server?

For example save it in public_html/../ftp  (just illustrating the path here).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I need to store everything outside public_html folder. Should I create a folder outside public_html folder and then store all the files there. How can I make sure that my script can save into it. I have never worked on live server it would really help me if you can guide me please